# MySQL - cannot order by value

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to order values in my database from highest to lowest.
The only thing it does now is randomly scramble up all results, meaning it just puts 100 below 50 in the middle and 1 in the top.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","table");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM playerdata ORDER BY Gold");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['Username'];
  echo " " . $row['Gold'];
  $row['Unique_ID'];
  echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Change `ORDER BY Gold` to `ORDER BY Gold DESC`

Comment: Providing the table definition is a good idea

Comment: is it really scrambled randomly, or is it just the opposite of the order you want?

Comment: Scrambled, not upsidedown like you say

Comment: The order `1, 50, 100` doesn't seem very random, it's the normal order.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Gold`?

Comment: Providing an example set of results too would help clarify what is "scrambled"

Comment: i think its solved guys.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM playerdata ORDER BY Gold DESC

Answer (score 1):

**Mysql does not order by value** but **Mysql does order by value based on the type** .
If we take an example : you have a table `TABLE1` that contain two columns `C1` and `C2` where `C1` is `INT` and `C2` is `VARCHAR`  and we have a set of :

```
C1    C2
1     1
2     2
10    10
```

so

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 ORDER BY C1 DESC
```

shows

```
C1    C2
10    10
2     2
1     1
```

but

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 ORDER BY C2 DESC
```

will shows

```
C1    C2
2     2
10    10
1     1
```

so pay attention to your schema and your data .